# Is it possible to reuse elements within a XAML document?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is it possible to declare a XAML fragment and re-use it in the same document? I have two Telerik RadGridView controls that should have identical column definitions and I would like to only have to declare them once:

```
                <telerik:RadGridView Name="FirstGrid">
                    <telerik:RadGridView.Columns Id="TheColumns">
                        <telerik:GridViewToggleRowDetailsColumn Width="20"/>
                        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Id" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Id}" Width="30"/>
                        ...
                    </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                </telerik:RadGridView>

                <telerik:RadGridView Name="SecondGrid">
                    <InsertCrossReferenceHere Id="TheColumns">
```

Obviously InsertCorssRefenceHere is a placeholder for the answer I am hoping for, so is Id in Columns.
I'm sure this is possible using something standard in XML but I can't find what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes, it is possible, but the longer answer is that it *could* be more trouble than it's worth. Well, it depends really on where you want to display these columns. For example, you could define them inside a [`DataTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a particular type of data and then anywhere that you displayed instances of that type, the UI would render each item as you defined.

However, I assume that this is *not* what you want. There are other ways that you can do this, but I suspect that the closest thing to what you want would be for you to define your UI in a [`UserControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as @dkozl suggested.

The basic idea is this... define your 'reusable' UI elements inside the `UserControl`. Add one or more [`DependencyProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)s to your `UserControl` and then data bind from the UI controls to the property, or properties of the property:

For example, in the `UserControl`, create a `DependencyProperty` of type `Address` and named `Address`. From inside the `UserControl`, use `RelativeSource FindAncestor Binding`s to connect with this property:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Street, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType={x:Type YourXmlNamespacePrefix:YourUserControl}}}" />
...
<TextBlock Text="{Binding PostCode, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType={x:Type YourXmlNamespacePrefix:YourUserControl}}}" />
```

Then, with a property named `Address` in the parent view model, you can data bind to the `UserControl` from outside like this:

```
<YourXmlNamespacePrefix:YourUserControl Address="{Binding Address}" />
```

Any place that you want to reuse your code, just add another one of these lines above.